# Problem with GraphQL and Next JS in Production build

Tags: build, graphql, next.js

I have a projectwhere I use `NextJS` and `GraphQL`. Everything was working fine until yesterday.

For `GraphQL` I am using `Apollo GraphQL`

Yesterday I added new field `pageDescription` to GraphQL query that I need to get from `review`. Here is part from `GraphQL schema`

```js
"Field Group"
type Review_Review {
    fieldGroupName: String
    "Page description that will be displayed in Google search"
    pageDescription: String
    reviewProducts: [Review_Review_reviewProducts]
}
```

And here is my query

```js
export const single_review_query = gql`
  query Review($slug: String) {
    reviewBy(slug: $slug) {
      content
      title
      featuredImage {
        sourceUrl
      }
      author {
        name
        description
        avatar(size: 32) {
          url
        }
        avatar_big: avatar(size: 60) {
          url
        }
      }
      review {
        pageDescription
        reviewProducts {
          products {
            pros
            title
            price
            notice
            platform
            link
            grade
            description
            cons
            image {
              image {
                sourceUrl
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

This query works like a charm in dev mode. The problem is when I run it in build. It just doesn't work. There is nothing in the console. Here is the error from `Networks` tab

```js
message: "Cannot query field "pageDescription" on type "Review_Review"."
category: "graphql"
```

Everything works fine when I remove `pageDescription` from query

Again. This doesn't happen in `DEV` mode

If you need more info write in comments.

Thank you.

**EDIT** Oh yeah. I forgot to mention. This is headless CMS that is using Wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a mistake on my side. I configured GraphQL to fetch data from localhost when in development mode and from the server in production mode and I didn't update GraphQL schema on the server. Only on localhost